# conda activate newenv returns "powerline-shell: command not found"

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I installed Conda using Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh. It works fine until today. I was able to run create new virtual env and activate it and then deactivate it as expected. Basically,

- `conda --version` was fine.
- `conda create -n newenv` was fine.
- `conda activate newenv` was fine too.

**Now, after creating an additional new env, conda refuses to activate it**, i.e. the command `conda activate newenv` returns `powerline-shell:command not found` and I need to kill the terminal.

What changed ? I have updated my conda version. I'm now running conda 4.8.3 under ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I check that conda activate and conda deactivate only work on conda 4.6 and later versions. Hence should work here with 4.8.3.

The new env appears in the list when running `conda env list`.

`echo $PATH` is showing among other things:

- `/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin`
- `/home/<user>/anaconda3/condabin`

I can install package using `conda install -n newenv numpy`. Works fine. I can list the packages in the new env.

**How come `conda activate` stopped working and other conda commands still work ? How can I fix it ?**

After numerous trials, I fixed it the following way:

1. remove powerline config from .bashrc file

   function _update_ps1() {
       PS1=$(powerline-shell $?)
   }

   if [[ $TERM != linux && ! $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ _update_ps1 ]]; then
       PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
   fi
2. `pip install powerline-shell`
3. Restore the config lines of powerline-shell in .bashrc

I'm not sure I fully understand the origin of the issue. In my opinion, the update of conda broke the dependency to powerline-shell package. Removing the lines from the .bashrc config allows me to understand that the problem is only linked to powershell and not to a deeper conda or commandline issue. Hence the idea to reinstall powershell package.

Answer (score 0):

**Note - Faced the same issue and fixed it.**

The issue comes from installing power-line shell in conda base environment and not in your local directory. So, each time you change your conda environment, the powerline-shell executable file is no longer available.

First of all make sure `which powerline-shell` returns `/home/$USER/.local/bin/powerline-shell`, where $USER is your user directory. If not, remove powerline-shell. Make sure to copy the configuration file if you have any.

Now, install powerline-shell using `pip3 install --user power-line-shell`. Ensure you have deactivate conda environment first (`base` environment too).

Finally, add `export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin/"` in your bashrc.